# Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal why?

Tags: c++, c++14

Why can't you do this?

```
constexpr auto foo()
{
    return "hello";
}

int main()
{
    // char s[] = foo();
    auto s2 = foo();
    const char* s3 = foo();
}
```

s give error. s2 and s3 are fine.

I thought this would be possible, but apparently not.

Yes I already know that you can't do this. None of you are explaining WHY you can't do this.

Comment: Return types and parameter types in C++ cannot be arrays. Arrays cannot be passed or returned as prvalues. (Moreover, arrays cannot be copy-initialized from arrays.)

Comment: So? Arrays can be initialized from string literals.

Comment: But you're not initializing it from a string literal here. You're initializing it from a function return value, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have neither copy constructors nor the copy assignment operators and functions may not have return types that are arrays.

But you may return a reference to an array. Below there is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto & foo()
{
    return "hello";
}

int main() 
{
    auto &s = foo();

    std::cout << sizeof( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
6
```

that is the size of the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is deduced as `char const*`. And as the compiler tells you very directly, initializers for `char` arrays have to be either braced-init-lists (i.e. `{…}`) or string literals.

Why then is the return type deduced as a pointer and not the array? You cannot return arrays. It's impossible as **in C++ arrays can't be copied**.
The placeholder return type is deduced "using the rules of template argument deduction for a function call".
And the same restriction applies to arrays as function parameters, thus template argument deduction will deduce a pointer type, [temp.deduct.call]/2:

> If `P` is not a reference type:
>
> - If `A` is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is used in place of `A` for
>     type deduction;

Hence the error. You simply *cannot* initialize an array with a return value of a function.

Comment: You're telling me what I already know... I'm asking why... there is no disadvantage to doing this.